Jenkins Pipeline Error: fatal: unable to access repo URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
I'm facing an issue with my Jenkins pipeline when trying to push changes to a remote Git repository. The error I'm getting is:
fatal: unable to access 'https://example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps.git/': URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
Here's the relevant part of my Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml '''
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    pod-name: jenkins-agent
spec:
  containers:
  - name: git
    image: alpine/git
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    env:
    - name: http_proxy
      value: proxyvalue
    - name: https_proxy
      value: proxyvalue
    - name: no_proxy
      value: somevalues,othersvalue
    volumeMounts:
    - name: yq-bin
      mountPath: /yq-bin
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "0.25"
  - name: jnlp
    image: jenkins/inbound-agent:latest
    args: ['$(JENKINS_SECRET)', '$(JENKINS_NAME)']
  initContainers:
  - name: yq
    image: mikefarah/yq:4.43.1
    command: ["sh", "-c", "cp /usr/bin/yq /yq-bin/yq"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: yq-bin
      mountPath: /yq-bin
  volumes:
  - name: yq-bin
    emptyDir: {}
            '''
        }
    }

    environment {
        HELM_HOME = "/usr/local/bin/helm"
        VALUES_FILE = "jenkins/values.yaml"
        GIT_REPO = "https://example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps.git"
        GIT_BRANCH = "master"
        NEW_BRANCH = "jenkins-update"
        GIT_CREDENTIALS_ID = "giteaAccess" 
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    git branch: "${env.GIT_BRANCH}", url: "${env.GIT_REPO}", credentialsId: "${env.GIT_CREDENTIALS_ID}"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Debug YQ Path') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    script {
                        sh 'ls -l /yq-bin'
                        sh '/yq-bin/yq --version'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Read Plugins') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    script {
                        def plugins = sh(script: "/yq-bin/yq e '.controller.installPlugins[]' ${env.VALUES_FILE}", returnStdout: true).trim().split("\n")
                        env.PLUGINS = plugins.join(" ")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Update Plugins') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    script {
                        def pluginsList = env.PLUGINS.tokenize()
                        sh "sed -i '/installPlugins:/,\$d' ${env.VALUES_FILE}"
                        sh "echo 'controller:' >> ${env.VALUES_FILE}"
                        sh "echo '  installPlugins:' >> ${env.VALUES_FILE}"
                        pluginsList.each { plugin ->
                            sh "echo '    - ${plugin}' >> ${env.VALUES_FILE}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Configure Git Safe Directory') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    script {
                        sh "git config --global --add safe.directory /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jenkinsupdater"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Commit Changes') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    script {
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_CREDENTIALS_ID}", usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
                            sh "git checkout -b ${env.NEW_BRANCH}"
                            sh 'git config user.email "username@example.org"'
                            sh 'git config user.name "${USERNAME}"'
                            sh 'git add ${VALUES_FILE}'
                            sh 'git commit -m "Automated update of Jenkins plugins"'
                            sh '''
                            git remote set-url origin https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps.git
                            git push -u origin ${NEW_BRANCH}
                            '''
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Create Pull Request') {
            steps {
                container('git') {
                    script {
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_CREDENTIALS_ID}", usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
                            sh """
                            curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} \
                            -d '{
                                  "title": "Automated update of Jenkins plugins",
                                  "body": "This PR includes automated updates of Jenkins plugins",
                                  "head": "${NEW_BRANCH}",
                                  "base": "master"
                                }' \
                            https://example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps/pulls
                            """
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            echo "Cleaning up and finalizing pipeline."
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}

I'm using Jenkins Kubernetes agents to run this pipeline. The pipeline checks out the repository, updates a values.yaml file with a list of Jenkins plugins, commits the changes, pushes a new branch to the remote repository, and creates a pull request.
I've tried to avoid directly embedding credentials into the URL to prevent security issues. The credentials are managed using Jenkins' withCredentials block.
Despite this, I still encounter the error related to the URL and port number. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Things I've checked/tried:

Ensuring credentials are correctly handled by withCredentials.
Using different ways to set the remote URL and push the changes.
Checking the proxy configuration.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Create a pull request to update plugins from gitops repo

Does the actual URL contain any characters other than letters, digits, dashes, and slashes?

yes, the usernamerepo has a spain nacional document something like this F7777777F, the url is https://example.org/git/F7777777X/devops-gitops-apps.git/

If your USERNAME environment variable contains @ character then that would explain the error. http://bob@gmail.com:Pasw00rd@example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps.git would result in bob being treated as a user name, gmail.com as a host name, and :Pasw00rd as a port number that is "not a decimal".
Any special characters in both the user name and the password would need to be url-encoded. Or avoided.
To bypass this problem entirely you could use the gitUsernamePassword parameter:
withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_CREDENTIALS_ID}",
                 gitToolName: 'Default')]) {
  sh 'git fetch --all'
}


in this case I configured this:
git remote set-url origin https://P9999988J:Pass00rd@example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps.git
git push -u origin ${NEW_BRANCH}

But my pass had a special charactes, is something like this:
http://P9999988J:Pasw00rd??@example.org/git/usernamerepo/devops-gitops-apps.git May I need to change the password or parse it ?

Or use gitUsernamePassword - see the updated answer

I changed the password and the pipeline works fine I will apply gitUsernamePassword.
thx
